# disabled the button when the Checkbox checked by default in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to disabled the button when the  Checkbox checked by default

here is my code :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Dis extends LightningElement {
    
    inputVal =true ;
    disableBtn;
    ischecked = true;

    handleChange(event){
      if(event.target.checked){
        this.disableBtn = true;
      }else{
        this.disableBtn = false;
      }
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>

    <lightning-input type="checkbox" checked={ischecked} value={inputVal} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>

    <lightning-button label='click me' disabled={disableBtn} ></lightning-button>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lightning button needs a boolean to hide/show it. You are not initializing, which means it's not true OR false. It's just null.

Ie, initialize your boolean like so:

```
disableButton=true;
```

And use the directive like this:

```
<lightning-button disabled={disableButton} label='click me' ></lightning-button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer

i want to disabled  the button when the checkbox is checked automatically

Comment: You need to be clear about what you are asking for. You changed your question after I answered it. Anyway, it's even easier. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer